# how to read data from ps/2 (usb-mouse) similary like I read serial port from arduino?

Tags: linux, usb, mouse

How to read data from ps/2 (usb-mouse) similary like I read serial port from arduino ?

For example when I press serial monitor in Arduino IDE or wen I type: "import processing.serial.*; ...... " in Processing I have a column of data from serial port (arduino)

How to read data similary data from usb mouse  ?? Can I  ? I have linux.